# Using utility types to remove object fields

Tags: typescript

I am using the `Omit` utility type to remove a `description` in `TodoPreview`, but when assigning a variable of type `TodoPreview` to another one of type `Todo` the omitted field is still present and doesn't get caught on compile time. Is there is way to get rid of the omitted field in `todo2:TodoPreview` by type declaration only?

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
  createdAt: number;
}

type TodoPreview = Omit<Todo, "description">;

const todo: Todo = {
  title: "Clean room",
  completed: false,
  createdAt: 1615544252770,
  description: "Test",
};

const todo2: TodoPreview = {
  ...todo
}

//Same result with `const todo2: TodoPreview = todo;`

console.log(todo2);
```

Since this can't be caught at compile time, it will produce the following result with `description` field present:

```
{
  "title": "Clean room",
  "completed": false,
  "createdAt": 1615544252770,
  "description": "Test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior since objects in typescript are considered somewhat open to extension with extra fields. The only places where extra fields can make types incompatible are ones where [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) happen. And your case is not one of them.

While you cannot assign an *object literal* with `extra` fields you can freely assign the same value when previously assigned to a variable

```ts
type A = {
    s: string
}

const bad: A = { s: '', n: 2 } // excess property check

let _good = { s: '', n: 2}
const good: A = _good // no error
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0QRN)

To explicitly forbid `description` field in the source object you have to make the type of `description` field explicitly unassignable:

```ts
type TodoPreview = Omit<Todo, "description"> & { description?: never };
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vjMm)